# How can I load a json file in the dojo application build profile?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following dojo build profile:

```
var profile = (function () {
    return {
        basePath: "./Scripts",
        releaseDir: "./bin",
        releaseName: "",
        action: "release",
        mini: true,
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        localeList: false,
        packages: [
            {
                name: "dojo",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dojo"
            },
            {
                name: "dijit",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dijit"
            },
            {
                name: "dojox",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dojox"
            },
            ...
        ],
        layers: ...
    };
})();
```

Now, I need to read values from some json file, so I am looking for something like this:

```
var profile = (function () {
    var versions = SomeHowReadTheContentsOf("ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json");
    return {
        basePath: "./Scripts",
        releaseDir: "./bin",
        releaseName: "",
        action: "release",
        mini: true,
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        optimize: "closure",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        localeList: false,
        packages: [
            {
                name: "dojo",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/" + versions["dojo-debug"] + "/dojo"
            },
            {
                name: "dijit",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/" + versions["dojo-debug"] + "/dijit"
            },
            {
                name: "dojox",
                location: "l:/dojo-debug/" + versions["dojo-debug"] + "/dojox"
            }
            ...
        ],
        layers: ...
    };
})();
```

For the life of me I am failing to find the way to do it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My command line is: `node L:\dojo-debug\1.10.4\dojo\dojo.js load=build --profile .\package.profile.js`

**EDIT2**

I have added a console log of all the properties of `require`, below is the result:

```
has = undefined
isXdUrl = undefined
initSyncLoader = undefined
eval = undefined
signal = undefined
on = undefined
map = undefined
rawConfig = undefined
legacyMode = undefined
async = undefined
waitms = undefined
baseUrl = undefined
idle = undefined
toAbsMid = undefined
toUrl = undefined
log = undefined
trace = undefined
injectUrl = undefined
getText = undefined
nodeRequire = undefined
uid = undefined
cache = undefined
packs = undefined
paths = undefined
aliases = undefined
modules = undefined
execQ = undefined
defQ = undefined
waiting = undefined
mapProgs = undefined
pathsMapProg = undefined
listenerQueues = undefined
computeMapProg = undefined
computeAliases = undefined
runMapProg = undefined
compactPath = undefined
getModuleInfo = undefined
boot = undefined
scopeify = undefined
```

So `nodeRequire` is there, but its value is `undefined`. Something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Dojo builder with NodeJS, you have access to its `require` via `require.nodeRequire`. Within a build profile file, you also have access to a variable called `selfPath` which is the absolute directory name of the profile file you have passed to the builder (it's similar to `__dirname` in a node module). Putting these two things together and assuming `ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json` is a sibling of your build profile:

```js
var profile = (function () {
    var req = require.nodeRequire;
    var path = req('path');
    var versions = req(path.join(selfPath, 'ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json'));
    return {
        ...
    };
})();
```

Comment: `require.nodeRequire` is undefined. I have added an EDIT to my post specifying the command line I am using.

Comment: I just tried this using the flies found at https://gist.github.com/bryanforbes/cea64894c0e5d77fccea and the profile successfully runs, `nodeRequire` is a function, and correctly parses the JSON file. I'm using OS X, but I would assume Windows would function similarly.

Comment: I am using node v0.12.1 and dojo 1.10.4 and I do console.log for each and every property in the `require` object. All I can see is that it has a lot of them, but they are all `undefined`.

Comment: Found it. Should be `this.require.nodeRequire`. But the `selfPath` is still not recognized.

Comment: I'm using node v0.12.2 and Dojo 1.10.4. Are you using a built version or the source version of Dojo?

Comment: I found the problem. First of all, it is `this.require.nodeRequire`. But I was wrong about `selfPath` being `undefined`. It is there alright. My problem is that in my case I have **package.profile.js** require **default.profile.js** and the latter require **ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json**. I was trying to use the same approach in the second case, forgetting that I am already in the node realm there. Anyway, all is OK now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Aha! Glad you figured it out.